# Compilation Process: Flow Chart

Tags: luatex, compiling

I am searching for a flow chart of the compilation process for `LuaLaTeX` (or `pdfLaTeX`).
The chart should include packages like `hyperref`, `varioref`, etc. that use additional calls of `lualatex.exe`.
Furthermore, I use glossary, bibliograhy and index functionality.

The more general question is: When do I have to call which program (TeX, xindy, makeglossarie, ...) to get a pdf with all defined functions.

Comment: May I ask: Have you read an introduction to LaTeX? There you should find all necceccary informations. You have to invoke 1. PdfLaTeX/LuaLaTeX 2. Biber/BibTeX Makeindex (other tools, if used) 3.  PdfLaTeX/LuaLaTeX 4. PdfLaTeX/LuaLaTeX

Comment: Of course you may ask. I read some guides and I know this process more or less. However, I remember a picture with a complex flow chart but I did not find it any more. I ask this question, because I am not sure about the compiling process. Currently, I compile that what I miss in the document. I will take a look in the docu and create a flow chart. Than I am happy for comments etc.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Compilation Process]
The green rectangles are necessary, whereas the blue ones are optional. What do you think?

Here is my code for further improvement.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone} 
% additional packages
\usepackage{amsmath, ifluatex, tikz}
\ifluatex
    \usepackage{fontspec                    % Spezifikation Zeichensatz
                    , lualatex-math     % Fixes for mathematics related LuaLATEX issues
                   }
\fi
% \input{../Font.tex}

% additional TikZ libraries
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

% define lengths
\newlength{\lenDist}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center, draw=black, scale=1]

    % add styles
    \tikzset{styRectDef/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black, inner xsep=6mm, inner ysep=3mm}}
    \tikzset{styRectOne/.style = {styRectDef, draw=green, fill=green!20}}
    \tikzset{styRectTwo/.style = {styRectDef, draw=cyan, fill=cyan!40}}
    \tikzset{styConn/.style = {very thick, ->, -latex, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm}}

    % set radius
    \setlength{\lenDist}{2cm}

    % nodes
    \node [styRectOne] (nlatex1) {1. Lua\LaTeX};
    \node [styRectTwo, right=\lenDist of nlatex1] (nindex) {2b. Index\\(Texindy)};
    \node [styRectTwo, above=of nindex] (nbiber) {2a. Bibliography\\(Biber)};
    \node [styRectTwo, below=of nindex] (nglossary) {2c. Glossary\\(MakeGlossaries)};
    \node [styRectOne, right=\lenDist of nindex] (nlatex2) {3. Lua\LaTeX};
    \node [styRectOne, right=\lenDist of nlatex2] (nlatex3) {4. Lua\LaTeX};

    % connections
    \draw[styConn, bend left] (nlatex1) to (nbiber);
    \draw[styConn] (nbiber) to (nindex);
    \draw[styConn] (nindex) to (nglossary);
    \draw[styConn, bend right] (nglossary) to (nlatex2);
    \draw[styConn] (nlatex2) to (nlatex3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think some more context and explanation might make this a more useful answer.  As it stands, the diagram doesn't tell me much more than a simple list of tasks.  Perhaps you could show the files consumed and created at each step?  To my mind a process diagram makes more sense if I can see processes operating on things.

Comment: The question aims at an easy overview of the compilation process. In the past I triggered the different process step more or less randomly. When I was asked for a process that always works, I had no answer. Hence it is not necessary for me to know about files etc, except it has an impact on the process. In addition, I choose this type to clarify the optional use of Biber etc. Do you think of process diagrams like this: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/flowcharts/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a flow chart for a generic TeX compilation process - this does not specifically address the detail of the question, but might provide some ideas for further development (and it's something I already had, so it is very little effort to share it).  The drawing code is (of course) Metapost, but I've  embedded it in a LuaLateX document using the `luamplib` package.

[image: Tex Compilation process]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmonofont{Monaco}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}

vardef mac_window(expr s,t) = image(
  fill unitsquare xscaled s yscaled 0.618s withcolor white;
  fill unitsquare xscaled s yscaled 1/25 s shifted (0,0.618s) withcolor 0.784 white;
  draw unitsquare xscaled s yscaled 0.658 s withpen pencircle scaled 0.2;
  fill fullcircle scaled 1/50 s shifted (1/40s, 0.638s) withcolor (233/255,  66/255,  63/255);
  fill fullcircle scaled 1/50 s shifted (5/80s, 0.638s) withcolor (255/255, 233/255, 125/255);
  fill fullcircle scaled 1/50 s shifted (4/40s, 0.638s) withcolor (180/255, 240/255, 140/255);
  draw fullcircle scaled 1/50 s shifted (1/40s, 0.638s) withpen pencircle scaled .1;
  draw fullcircle scaled 1/50 s shifted (5/80s, 0.638s) withpen pencircle scaled .1;
  draw fullcircle scaled 1/50 s shifted (4/40s, 0.638s) withpen pencircle scaled .1;
  label(t,(1/2s, 0.309s));
  ) enddef;

vardef paper_file(expr s, t) = image(
  save p, ear, r; r=0.21; 
  path p; p = (origin -- right -- (1,1.414-r) -- (1-r,1.414) 
                               -- (0,1.414) -- cycle) scaled s;
  path ear;                              
  ear = point 2 of p -- point 3 of p -- (xpart point 3 of p, ypart point 2 of p) -- cycle;
  fill p withcolor white;
  fill ear withcolor .9 white;
  draw p; draw ear;
  label(t,center p);
  ) enddef;

vardef process(expr s, t) = image(
  save p; path p; p = unitsquare shifted -(1/2,1/2) xscaled s yscaled 0.618 s; 
  fill p withcolor white - 1/4 blue;
  draw p; label(t, center p);
) enddef;

def connecting(expr p, q) = center p -- center q cutbefore bbox p cutafter bbox q enddef;

beginfig(1);
fill unitsquare yscaled 9cm xscaled 14cm shifted (-1cm,-1/2cm) withcolor (241/255, 241/255, 231/255);

picture vim, skim, tex, pdf, aux, log, inputs, comp;

vim  = mac_window(3cm, btex VIM etex);
skim = mac_window(3cm, btex Skim etex) shifted (8cm * right);

tex = paper_file(2cm, btex \TeX etex) shifted (.5cm,4cm);
pdf = paper_file(2cm, btex PDF etex) shifted (8.5cm,4cm);

log = paper_file(9mm, btex .log etex) shifted (11cm, 6.5cm);
aux = paper_file(9mm, btex .aux etex) shifted (7cm, 6.5cm);

comp = process(2cm, btex xelatex etex) shifted 1/2[center tex, center pdf];

inputs = thelabel(btex $\vcenter{\halign{\hfil#\hfil\cr Macros\cr Fonts\cr Graphics\cr}}$ etex scaled .8, 
                  center comp shifted 60 up);

path a[]; 
a1 = connecting(vim,tex);
a2 = connecting(skim,pdf);
a3 = connecting(tex,pdf);

drawarrow a1 dashed evenly; label.lft("edit, save" infont "phvro8r" scaled .7 , point 1/2 of a1);
drawarrow a2 dashed evenly; label.lft("view, print" infont "phvro8r" scaled .7 , point 1/2 of a2); 
drawarrow a3;

drawarrow center comp { right } .. center log cutafter bbox log;
drawarrow center comp { right } .. center aux cutafter bbox aux;
drawarrow center aux { left } .. center comp cutbefore bbox aux cutafter bbox comp;

drawarrow connecting(inputs,comp);

draw comp;
draw inputs;
draw vim; draw tex;
draw skim; draw pdf; draw log; draw aux;

drawoptions(withcolor .56 red);
a4 = connecting(vim,comp); drawarrow a4 dashed withdots scaled .4;
a5 = connecting(vim,skim); drawarrow a5 dashed withdots scaled .4;
label.rt ("!xelatex %"            infont "texnansi-lmtt10" scaled .8, point 1/2 of a4);
label.top("!open -a Skim %:r.pdf" infont "texnansi-lmtt10" scaled .8, point 1/2 of a5);

endfig;
end.
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```