# Toolchain, to compile a lualatex document with biber and xindy?

Tags: cross-referencing, luatex, compiling, biber, xindy

Which are the required steps to compile LuaLaTeX plus biber, and xindy to pdf latex? I tried it with the following bash script,

```
#!/bin/bash

MYPRJ="masterfile"
LUAOPTIONS="--halt-on-error --output-format="pdf" --shell-escape --synctex=1 --interaction=nonstopmode"

lualatex ${LUAOPTIONS} ${MYPRJ}.tex
biber ${MYPRJ}.bcf
makeglossaries ${MYPRJ}
lualatex ${LUAOPTIONS} ${MYPRJ}.tex
lualatex ${LUAOPTIONS} ${MYPRJ}.tex
```

but the logfile claims that the `\cref` links could not be referenced.

Comment: Why don't you just use [`arara`](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb36-1/tb112cereda.pdf)?

Comment: @HenriMenke There are many build tools. I am debugging a problem with my favorite one right now. First I want to understand what is happening and where I make a mistake.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271447/compilation-process-flow-chart

Comment: Is there any news here? May it be closed?

Comment: @TeXnician No. There is no reason to close it. The order of commands is no rocket science, but always a bit confusing. It is possible (at least in theory) to compile manually step by step without magic tools like arara, mklatex and friends.

Comment: Well, I just asked, because you mentioned a possible duplicate yourself.